# How can I prevent HTML duplication in WordPress website?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have written some PHP and HTML code to insert social share buttons at the top and bottom of each post.

Since the buttons appear twice on the same page, I had to copy paste the same HTML at two locations.

Is there any way for me to save the HTML code just once at some place and then output it using WordPress `shortcodes` or anything else like that? I just want to avoid copy pasting the same HTML whenever I need to add share buttons in different places.

Update:

The social media links are generated using the following code (similarly for other networks like Twitter etc.):

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink());?>" class="fb"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
```

I need a way to get the premalink and title etc. properly from the shortcode function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can achieve this by using hooks. I use [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) hook here. So you don't need to alter any template system. Create a small function in functions.php in your theme.

```
function yourtheme_before_after($content) {
    global $post;

    $socialIcons = '<a href="share.php?u='.get_permalink($post).'">Facebook</a>';
    $socialIcons .= '<a>Twitter</a>';
    $socialIcons .= '<a>Pintrest</a>';

    $beforecontent = $socialIcons;
    $aftercontent = $socialIcons;
    $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;

    return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'yourtheme_before_after');
```

Basically, you append the post content after your custom content, then return the result.

Note: You can modify the social icon part using css/html

**EDIT** :Added the **global $post** in the function, you can get pretty much everything related to post.

Comment: Thanks @Rinto. :)

I forgot to mention that the social media links will be generated dynamically based on the post and won't have static HTML. Will this technique still work?

I have updated my question to add details.